# Adding Data to a very nested child object using EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, addition

[image]

I am trying to add a note to my event object. I am getting an error using this code

```
  Note noteToAdd = new Note { State = State.Added, NoteText = note };
  Patient patient = context.Patients.Find(patientId);
  patient.State = State.Modified;
  patient.MobilePatient.State = State.Modified;
  patient.MobilePatient.MCalmEvents.Find(e => e.Id == eventid).Note = noteToAdd;
  context.ApplyStateChanges();
```

Is there a better way to do it using Linq To Entity?

The error that I am having is :

> {"Invalid column name 'Note_Id'."}

and the SQl that is being generated is a SELECT instead of INSERT.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but your map shows a one-to-many relation between `Note` and `Event`...

all of your code remain as they are, but instead of this line :

```
patient.MobilePatient.MCalmEvents.Find(e => e.Id == eventid).Note = noteToAdd;
```

replace these lines:

```
noteToAdd.EventID = oEvent.ID; // replace field names, to exactly what they are; 
context.Note.Add(noteToAdd);
var oEvent = patient.MobilePatient.MCalmEvents.Find(e => e.Id == eventid);
oEvent.NoteID = noteToAdd.ID; // replace field names, to exactly what they are;
```

also i think if you don`t write these two:

```
var oEvent = patient.MobilePatient.MCalmEvents.Find(e => e.Id == eventid);
oEvent.NoteID = noteToAdd.ID; // replace field names, to exactly what they are;
```

there is not any problem, i`m not sure

Comment: Thank you for help @am1r_5h when I recheck the code the issue was in the database table that had a Note table named as Notes. I generate the db again and the first code works properly. I also check you solution and it works too thanks you

Comment: whereas you use `entityframework`, can you answer to my question ? [what are `edmfunctions` for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607456/what-are-edmfunctions-for)

Answer (score 0):

According to your map, `Event` entity has a list of `Note` as navigation property, and i think you should add to this collection instead, what you write in this line:

```
patient.MobilePatient.MCalmEvents.Find(e => e.Id == eventid).Note = noteToAdd;
```

i think should be like this:

```
patient.MobilePatient.MCalmEvents.Find(e => e.Id == eventid).Add(noteToAdd);
```

in addition, what kind of error you get ? can you explain your error ?

Comment: Thank you. Your proposal solution was the something but the Add method does not exist in the MCalmEvent. The error that I am having is : {"Invalid column name 'Note_Id'."} and the SQl that is being generated is a SELECT instead and Insert.

Comment: The schema is that MobilePatient has a list of Event=MCalmEvents and each event has only one note.

Comment: but your map shows a one-to-many relation between `Note` and `Event`

Answer (score 0):

are sure there is no add method on `Event` navigation property
why don`t you try to add note from context directly? like:

```
context.Note.Add(noteToAdd);
```

Comment: Yes I am sure I am having and error if I try to use Add. If I do context.Note.Add how I will be specifying the patient and the specific event that has that note?