# what are 'EdmFunctions' for?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, clr

i saw the `System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.EdmFunctions` static class accidently, that contains a set of extension methods on `System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpression`, like AddDays, Concat,.... which bring back `System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbFunctionExpression` as return type, this static methods if needs to an argument, they only accept a `System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpression` type, in addition i look over the `System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpression` and i saw this class is abstract and by its static members you can create a  `System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpression`, and send them to `System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.EdmFunctions` to use its extension methods,

my questions are:

- what are these extensions for ?
- how and where can we use this extension methods ?
- have these extension methods mapped to `canonical functions` and are as helper method for using in `Linq`, like `System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions`'s methods  or `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions`'s Methods ?

whereas there is a attribute with name `System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmFunction` and by this, you can create `CLR` functions and map them to created `model-defined functions` for using in `Linq`,

- is there a relation between these ?

could you attach any sample? or link to any documentaion?

Answer (score 4):

These methods are not meant for general consumption, you continue to use `SqlFunctions` or `EntityFunctions` in client code.  They are the stock implementations of the canonical functions that can execute on an arbitrary provider.  Microsoft includes the providers for XML, BCL collections and Entity SQL.  Somebody else can create a provider to, say, their own dbase engine or ORM.

The mapping from, say, [`EntityFunctions.AddDays()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412479%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [`EdmFunctions.AddDays()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.commandtrees.expressionbuilder.edmfunctions.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) occurs dynamically when the query comprehension is executed.